# Allowing options in ManyToMany to be selected by one object at a time

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model defined as follows:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
```

I need to prevent countries from being assigned to multiple groups via the Django Admin.

How can I achieve that?

I realize I can just place `group = models.ForeignKey` on my `Country` model instead of the ManyToMany  relationship but that will change how things are edited on Django Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My strong recommendation is to have your database structure accurately reflect your data model, rather than basing it on what produces the most convenient default forms in Django. It's not hard to customize forms, but it is hard to avoid, and dangerous to tolerate, data corruption. For example, if you do as you suggest that won't do anything to prevent the creation of invalid data through other means (views, the console, etc.)

So one option is to use a `ForeignKey` constraint, as you suggested.

A compromise solution would be to keep the `ManyToManyField` and put the relevant constraint on the `through` model. That would allow you to keep using whatever forms you're currently using. Something like:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country, through="GroupCountry")

class GroupCountry(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, unique=True)
```

Note that any solution involving a `ManyToManyField` will have a performance penalty since there's an additional table to be joined. Also note that this change involves a potentially complicated migration; you can find some questions and answers on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, I will stick with ForeignKey.